# Ubuntu USB does not continue after pressing "Install Ubuntu"

Tags: system-installation, acer

Using Acer E5-771G with Windows 10 UEFI, and trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 from a USB installed with Rufus, but when I select `Install Ubuntu` the screen becomes in black and does not continue.

Comment: ...and what are the hardware specs? Also, what is that button you push to install Ubuntu?

Comment: It's almost certainly this one. https://linus.nci.nih.gov/bdge/images/ubuntu/image020.png

Answer (score 1):

This class of failure mostly arises from corrupt boot media.

Please check the checksum on your ISO file before making the USB through Rufus. Each repository lists the MD5, SHA-1 and SHA-256 checksums.

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VerifyIsoHowto for further instructions.